# heat accumulation tank: hot water IN from top or bottom?

Tags: heating-systems, hvac

should heated water from a wood boiler enter a vertical cylindrical heat accumulation tank from the top or the bottom?

mine goes in from the top and can barely achieve more than 60C, whilst the boiler is capped at 85C

this is a closed loop system for underfloor heating

Comment: It's a little difficult to say without more details of the setup, but generally speaking if the water falls into the tank you can lose heat to the air in the headspace and the tank walls. Check the quality of insulation from the boiler and all around the tank; your problems may come from some other factor.

Comment: Does it really fill at the top? Typical gas hot water heater ,the pipe enters the top and goes to the bottom of the tank where cold water is discharged.

Comment: to clafiry: this is a closed loop system for underfloor heating

Comment: See my answer I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

Most storage tanks I have encountered have the boiler connections roughly in the middle of the tank.

Some tanks have two boiler loops and the one with the more "expensive" fuel (eg a gas boiler) is connected to the upper loop.

Had a tank with 2 boiler loops and one was for the gas boiler and the lower one used for the wood stove. This meant the gas boiler did less work when the wood stove was lit.

Then, when solar was added, that was at the bottom of the tank so that any heat added by the solar reduced the heat input needed from either wood or gas.

However, I did use a tank as a mixing tank in a special situation, which was a large underfloor system heated from a 5000l tank heated by solar panels. To get thorough mixing we put the hotter water into the top of the tank and drew out at the desired temperature from the bottom - this worked since there was a constant demand and flow - it would not work if the demand was not continuous as water stratifies when stationary.